# Flutter web blank screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am doing flutter web.First app(counter) work good,but when i am adding new dependencies like `cloud_firestore:` or adding new code files i am having blank screen without any errors.
I use channel master.
I do not understand what the problem is

Comment: check your browser console for error logs and add them to your question

Answer (score 0):

in some questions, you should make clear your stuck. I think you should update your question.

We need to know about your flutter version, you can see it by run terminal and type "flutter doctor -v". And logs of your case.

In the other hand, I think you should first glance [cloud_firestore documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/install) and it's [git repo issues.](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues)

Then, I think if you work with flutter web, you should use beta channel, be recommended by [flutter document](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web)